# convert from string to double fails to convert as expected

Tags: c++11

I am trying to convert "21898.99" to a string I but keep on getting 21898.990000000002 but I am expecting 21898.99

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    double d1 = std::strtod("21898.99", nullptr);
    long double d2 = std::strtold("21898.99", nullptr);
    float d3 = std::strtof("21898.99", nullptr);

    double d4 = atof("21898.99");

    double d5 = boost::lexical_cast<double>("21898.99");

    double d6;  
    sscanf_s("21898.99", "%lf", &d6);

    double d7;
    sscanf_s("21898.99", "%lg", &d7);

    std::istringstream ss("21898.99");
    double d8 = 0.0;
    ss >> d8;

    typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl;
    std::cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10);
    std::cout << d1 << "\n";
    std::cout << d2 << "\n";
    std::cout << d3 << "\n";
    std::cout << d4 << "\n";
    std::cout << d5 << "\n";
    std::cout << d6 << "\n";
    std::cout << d7 << "\n";
    std::cout << d8 << "\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
21898.990000000002
21898.990000000002
21898.990234375
21898.990000000002
21898.990000000002
21898.990000000002
21898.990000000002
21898.990000000002
```

Windows 10 version 10.0.14939.0
Visual Studio 2017 15.9.0, C++ 19.15.26732.1
Windows SDK 10.0.17134.0

I tried on a centos machine with gcc and this call works, but the others also fail.
long double d2 = std::strtold("21898.99", nullptr);
since it returns 21898.99

Comment: Not sure I follow what the problem is, in most cases `max_digits10` is 17 for doubles. You're asking for 17 digits of precision, and double precision can be off by approx `2^-53` or `1.11*10^-16` it seems like what you're getting when asking for all digits is within the margin of error. Perhaps ask for `max_digits10 - 1` instead?

Comment: @Enfyve I am a bit confused with your comment. The 2 occurs at the 12th digit. If I count from before the decimal seperator it is in fact at after 17 numbers.

Comment: Exactly, all the digits are counted, not just those after the point. That's what floating point means: the number of digits is (basically) constant but the location of the decimal point is variable (floating).

Comment: Do you have any ideas what I can do to get exactly 21898.99 and also have this work in general? For example "21898123.99" gives 21898123.989999998

Comment: The tipical link for this kind of questions would be http://diybigdata.net/2016/07/data-science-and-floating-point-arithmetic/ . If you *really* need to have a precision of exactly two digits after the point, you could store and use an integer value 100 times greater (2189899, with a proper sized type) and pretend to have a floating point only when printing its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for floating point numbers; some values are not exactly representable.

Comment: I will add this as the answer because of the good comments below the Q